# SharePoint Online _api/contextinfo 401 error

Tags: http, sharepoint

Using HTTP client in C# to interact with SharePoint. GET request run ok with json odata returned.

I am trying to get Form digest value using {siteurl}/_api/contextinfo and continually hitting a 401 response error.  My code is below -

I have looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/navigate-the-sharepoint-data-structure-represented-in-the-rest-service as well and other than a possible conflict with url formats shown on that page (i have tried both formats) -
a. POST https://{site_url}/_api/contextinfo
b. POST https://{site_url}/_api/doclib/contextinfo

the url string below builds to https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/sites/sitename/_api/context

I am still getting the same error - can anyone suggest solution

```
`    `url = @"https://" + HostSite + @"/" + SiteRoot + "/_api/contextinfo";


      requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
     {
         Method = HttpMethod.Post,
         Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
         RequestUri = new Uri(url),


     };
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
     requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);

     response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

looked at SharePoint API guidance and it indicates that it should work but still get 401 error. Have set API permissions in Entra Id for Graph and SharePoint for Site manage all level.